# Finiteness of theta vanishing in the KP direction for locally planar curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

I believe the main question is Question 2 at the end, and for experts it might be completely okay to skip directly to it (assuming I'm not saying any nonsense).

My motivation comes from pure algebraic geometry, so I will first explain the algebro-geometric story.

Let $C$ a reduced irreducible (I can assume locally planar) projective algebraic curve over ${\mathbb C}$ of arithmetic genus $g \geq 2$, and $p \in C$ a smooth point of $C$. Let $\mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}(C) \simeq \mathrm{Jac}(C)$ be the (non-compactified) Jacobian of $C$, and consider the theta divisor
$$ \Theta = \{ {\mathscr L} \in \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}(C): h^0({\mathscr L}) > 0 \}. $$
There is a canonical map $T_pC \hookrightarrow H^1(C,{\mathscr O}_C)$ obtained from the identification $T_pC = H^0({\mathscr O}_C(p) \otimes {\mathscr O}_p)$ and the coboundary map $H^0({\mathscr O}_C(p) \otimes {\mathscr O}_p) \to H^1(C,{\mathscr O}_C)$ from the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to {\mathscr O}_C \to {\mathscr O}_C(p) \to {\mathscr O}_C(p) \otimes {\mathscr O}_p \to 0. $$
This gives a direction at all points of $\mathrm{Pic}(C)$, which apparently is called the KP (Kadomtsev-Petviashvili) direction, cf. the analytic story below. Consider a small complex-analytic curve (open disk) $\Delta \subset \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}(C)$ that is a straight line in the KP direction.

**Fact.** If $C$ is smooth, it is known that $\Delta$ can't be contained in $\Theta$.

**Question 1.** If $C$ is singular (I can assume locally planar), is this still (known and) true?

Now the analytic story.

The way in which the Fact above is known is not what I would have imagined. It follows from [SW, Proposition 8.6 and Theorem 9.11] (and also from [F]). A footnote in [BV] states that no direct geometric proof is known. I have no idea if anything has changed since [BV] was written. It seems to me that in order to answer Question 1, what is needed is a version of [SW, Theorem 9.11] for singular curves. Is there such a thing?

**Question 2.** Can the relation between $\theta$ and $\tau$ functions in [SW, Theorem 9.11] be extended to singular curves? Locally planar curves are good enough for my purposes.

I am completely ignorant about this analytic story, and I've first encountered it only extremely recently.

*References:*

[BV] C. Birkenhake and P. Vanhaecke, *The Vanishing of the Theta Function in the KP Direction: A Geometric Approach*, Compos. Math. 135, 323-330 (2003)

[F] J. Fay, *On the even-order vanishing of Jacobian theta functions*, Duke Math. J. 51, 109-132 (1984)

[SW] G. Segal and G. Wilson G, *Loop groups and equations of KdV type*, Publ. Math. IHES 61, 5-65 (1985)